# How can unused/orphaned Google OAuth2 token be removed?

Tags: google-api, google-oauth

We have an app that over time obtained and worked with Google OAuth2 tokens. Now it got the `'Unverified app'` status allowing < 100 installs. We know we have < 100 users with active access tokens but the Google OAuth team tells us there are > 100 outstanding access tokens.

How can we revoke those unused/orphaned tokens that our app does not track anymore? We can't issue the 'revoke' requests because we don't know those tokens. Is there a way for an app to list all outstanding oauth2 tokens or to revoke all its tokens?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Such an access token has a lifetime of about an hour - you probably mean app authorizations aka "Third-party sites & apps with access to your account", which last until being revoked by the user. So generally there's not much to do about it, unless suggesting the users to revoke the access manually. Changing the name of the package might be the only option available on your side, to get rid of them.

Comment: Martin, what do you mean by changing the name of the package? In the Google API console you have projects and there is an app name in the consent screen. Is there a way to change something in the project to invalidate all outstanding refresh tokens?

Answer (score 0):

## Authorized users

First off you don't have `unused/orphaned tokens` not really.  What you have is users who have granted your application permission to access their data.  **There is no way for you to see exactly who these users are. There is no way to remove their granted consent unless you have refresh tokens for each of them saved in your system some place.**  If you do you could call a [revoke](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2UserAgent#tokenrevoke) on all of those refresh tokens and it should / might release a few of your 100 installs.   This is just a guess i have never tried it.

```
curl -H "Content-type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
      https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/revoke?token={token}
```

## application verification

The issue you are having is that your application is unverified. Google has placed a limit of 100 installs on unverified applications during the development process this way you can test your application before it goes live.  What you should do is go to Google developer console and request that your application be Verified.

> An unverified app is an app or Apps Script that requests a sensitive or restricted OAuth scope, but hasn't gone through the Google verification process. Users of unverified apps or your test builds might get warnings based on the OAuth scopes you're using. This is to protect users and their data from deceptive apps.

Once your application has been verified you will no longer be under the 100 installs limitation. You need to go though the [verification process](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/7454865?hl=en).

Comment: those tokens are _unknown_, so how are you going to revoke them? besides the actual question might rather be, why the app became unverified, which would rather be a leading approach.

Comment: Martin, exactly. We don't know those tokens that we want to revoke :( As for the unverified app mode we chose to stay in that mode because Google asks us to pay their security assessment firms $16,000 annually to have our app verified. It sounds like Google's 100 installs calculations are broken if they take into account tokens that are not used and have not been renewed for a long long time and we or they don't have any way to purge the stale the unnecessary tokens.

Comment: DalTo I am very familiar with the app verification process, we've been in it for over 6 months. But it all comes down to paying alot ($15k to $75k annually) to one of two Google chosen security firms for a security review. We can't afford this at the moment and our app has <100 users.

Comment: If you don&#39;t have the refresh tokens you can&#39;t revoke them.  They aren&#39;t not used the user could choose to use it at any time.   the 109 installs is only attended for testing.   If you have an application you should verify it for the security of your customers.  Pass the cost of verification on to your customers and consider it a part of doing business with Google apis.

Comment: We verify our apps for security using other vendors that offer more reasonable pricing. We're also a Salesforce ISV partner which actually helps review security for its partners/developers. This is probably not the place to talk about Google's verification process enabling a major shake down of developers by those two security firms but the price of doing business with Google has become too high. With three apps that we have we would be looking at paying $60k-90k. I don't think many SMB's can afford such costs. See this: https://www.theregister.co.uk/2019/02/11/google_gmail_developer/

Comment: If you feel that the price is to high then i think you should switch to another email provider.  If enough developers feel like you then maybe google will set the price down.   Even though its not them setting the price its a third party that does the security checks its them you are paying not google really.

Comment: **The situation underscores the business risks of relying on platform rules that are subject to change at any time but not subject to neutral oversight.**  Directly from your article. Switch mail providers if your not happy with approval process for the free service google is supplying.

Comment: We're providing a service to users who choose their provider. We can't switch a provider, we either support one or not. But yes, more and more we're serving users that choose Office 365 over G Suite.

Comment: We diverged here to "unverified app" but the question remains, is there a way for an app owner to revoke all outstanding grants/tokens and start from count zero? Thanks

Comment: @Alexey as stated only if you have the refresh tokens that were created by each user.   There is no way for the app owner to get a list of who has installed their application.

Comment: If a token is not revoked and abandoned/forgotten will it be invalidated and discarded at some point by Google? In a few months or a year? I guess I mean a refresh token.

Comment: @Alexey i "think" if a user revokes your access it should be unlocked.   This is what google has told me but in my experience it doesn't.